# Flutter custom scroll view lazy render

Tags: flutter, performance, dart

Is there any way to lazy render `CustomScrollView` content?

Appratenly, `CustomScrollView` rendering all slivers at once and it causes perfomance issues.

`items` is list of Slivers, so `ListView.builder` or `SliverList` is not possible to use

My code:

```
  Widget _build({required List<Widget> items}) {
    return ScrollListener(
      onScroll: (e) => onScroll?.call(),
      onEnd: () => onScroll?.call(),
      child: CustomScrollView(
        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: pageScrollController,
        slivers: items,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Try swapping `CustomScrollView` for a `ListView` and using a builder delegate instead of passing a fixed list.

Comment: Sure you need to use `SliverChildBuilderDelegate` directly which `ListView.builder` uses behind the scenes.

Comment: ```items``` is list of Slivers, not Widgets. ```SliverListBuilder``` needs a widget, so does ```ListView.builder```

Comment: and how many `items` do you have? also, what kind of slivers they are? `SliverToBoxAdapter`s, `SliverList`s?

Comment: @pskink, all of the kinds, that's why I don't use ```RenderBox``` widgets.

Comment: and how many `items` do you have if the "rendering" causes performance issues? is it hundreds? or thousands maybe? if that big why cannot you use `SliverList` as one of the slivers?